# Calling solidity function from backend

Tags: solidity

I would like to call a function which returns a boolean. How would I go about calling this function and storing the true or false in a variable? I have tried this `var result = contract.checkCertHash(certid,hashedData,address);` and initialised the contract using : `var parsed= JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonFile));
const abi = parsed.abi;
 const contract =  new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0xce395e1f6532e128f35469bb304ca46660a9f376');`

I tried searching over here but I have tried what I found but none worked. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your contract look like? I'm guessing your function is not `view` or `pure` so you can't get the return value directly.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way that works(Answering my own question): 
`contract.methods.checkCertHash(certid,hashedData,address).call().then(function(result){}`